# Facing issues while integrating Angular application with SSO on Teams Desktop client

Tags: angular, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

We have developed an angular application deployed on AKS with SSO enabled via Microsoft Entra App.

On Application level we are handling login same as this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript2). We were able to integrate the application in teams using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/teams-developer-portal) and was successfully login to our application in team web app in browser with SSO popup.

The same application configuration we are trying to access it from teams desktop client, the popup is flashing and disappearing.

Please let me know if I was missing any other configurations which it is not allowing the popup for signing in and help me to resolve this issue in MS teams desktop client.

Comment: There's no way we can help you without details at all. Basically you are saying "I did what they told me to do but it does not work" There is no way for us to see if you did something wrong or forgot anything.

Answer (score 0):

The Entra Id article you've linked is totally incorrect for Teams, because it's geared towards a standalone scenario. If the user goes to the totally standalone "web" view of your tab, that would work, but for integrating within Teams, you're in a constrained iframe environment and can't launch a popup or similar. To deal with this, Microsoft actually provides an entire framework for SSO in Tabs though - you just need to follow the correct guidance. Start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/tab-sso-overview which provides a step by step guide.